# Error when creating symbolic link in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, console, laravel-5, storage, laravel-artisan

I have a problem occured when creating a symbolic link in laravel 5.2

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "storage" namespace.

Here I haven't make any consoles in the laravel project folder . What I need is to make a symbolic link to public disk that publicly accessible . Laravel offical documentation said that "storage:link" artisan command is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `storage:link` artisan command is a 5.3 feature. Since you're using Laravel 5.2, you need to upgrade in order to use the command.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the correct path. I've refered this [laravel master](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk) link and found that this [laravel docs 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem) has the answer.I'll check that.